# read data between the lines java

Tags: java

I have a process that collects NMON data every 15 minutes. I have a basic understanding of reading the content into List or just use Java 8 Stream.

I am having difficulty iterating data between `ZZZZ,T0001.xxxx` and  `ZZZZ,T000X,xxx`

1. Read data between `ZZZZ,T0001,00:15:39,15-NOV-2019` to `ZZZZ,T0002,00:30:39,15-NOV-2019`
2. Add `CPU_ALL,T0001,7.3,1.6,0.3,90.9,8.8,48` to CPUData (Entity)
   `new CPUData('15-NOV-2019','00:15:39',7.3,1.6,0.3,90.9,8.8,48);`
3. other data entitiies

Repeat till last ZZZZ entry found.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My current test case

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dirName = "c:\\sampleFiles";
        String fileName = "c:\\sampleFiles\\test.nmon";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Files.list(new File(dirName).toPath())
            .forEach(path-> {
                System.out.println(path);
                 BufferedReader reader;
                FileReader fileReader;
                try {
                    fileReader = new FileReader(path.toString());
                    reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    while (line != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line = reader.readLine();
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here are the lines for trying iterative process

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))){
            list = stream.filter(line -> line.startsWith("ZZZZ")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
ZZZZ,T0001,00:15:39,15-NOV-2019
ZZZZ,T0002,00:30:39,15-NOV-2019
ZZZZ,T0003,00:45:39,15-NOV-2019
ZZZZ,T0004,01:00:39,15-NOV-2019
ZZZZ,T0005,01:15:39,15-NOV-2019
...
...
```

Here is a sample data from a NMON file...

```
BBBP,514,netstat,"Route Tree for Protocol Family 24 (Internet v6):"
BBBP,515,netstat,"::1%1              ::1%1             UH        3   2275817 lo0      -      -   "
BBBP,516,emgr -l
ZZZZ,T0001,00:15:39,15-NOV-2019
CPU01,T0001,26.0,7.7,14.7,51.6
CPU02,T0001,0.5,0.2,0.1,99.2
CPU03,T0001,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU04,T0001,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU05,T0001,0.0,0.1,0.0,99.9
CPU06,T0001,0.0,0.1,0.0,99.9
CPU07,T0001,0.0,0.1,0.0,99.9
CPU08,T0001,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU09,T0001,10.3,1.7,3.9,84.1
CPU10,T0001,0.1,2.4,0.0,97.5
CPU11,T0001,0.0,2.4,0.0,97.6
CPU12,T0001,0.0,2.4,0.0,97.6
CPU13,T0001,0.0,2.4,0.0,97.6
CPU14,T0001,0.0,2.4,0.0,97.6
CPU15,T0001,0.0,2.4,0.0,97.6
CPU16,T0001,0.0,2.4,0.0,97.6
CPU17,T0001,4.8,2.8,1.4,91.0
CPU18,T0001,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU19,T0001,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU20,T0001,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU21,T0001,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU22,T0001,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU23,T0001,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU24,T0001,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU25,T0001,1.3,2.7,0.3,95.6
CPU26,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU27,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU28,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU29,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU30,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU31,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU32,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU33,T0001,0.2,2.9,0.0,96.8
CPU34,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU35,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU36,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU37,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU38,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU39,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU40,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU41,T0001,0.0,0.3,0.0,99.7
CPU42,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU43,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU44,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU45,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU46,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU47,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU48,T0001,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU_ALL,T0001,7.3,1.6,0.3,90.9,8.8,48
BBBL,21,Flags,LPARed DRable SMT Shared UnCapped Migratable Not-Donating AMSable.
LPAR,T0001,0.554,6,48,16,2.00,128,0.00,3.46,3.46,1,0,7.26,1.56,0.06,18.81,2.42,0.52,0.02,6.27,0,0
POOLS,T0001,16,16.00,10.10,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,2.00
MEM,T0001,0.3,96.4,111.0,15797.4,36864.0,16384.0
MEMNEW,T0001,76.5,8.2,15.0,0.3,20.1,81.0
MEMUSE,T0001,8.2,3.0,90.0,960,1088,8.2,90.0, 9076000.0
PAGE,T0001,2200.6,1036.6,32.5,0.0,0.0,891.4,1940.5,0.0
MEMPAGES4KB,T0001,1556096,12859,774555,0,774555,682363,960,1088,0,0,682363,0,860874,501133,0,3655,37025,0,120731,1051308,1126800,0,146506,1047563,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
MEMPAGES64KB,T0001,492568,972,0,0,0,500238,60,68,0,0,491596,0,0,86831,0,0,7072,0,49256,405737,464431,0,79516,412066,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
MEMPAGES16MB,T0001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
MEMPAGES16GB,T0001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LARGEPAGE,T0001,0,0,0,0,16.0
PAGING,T0001,15798
PROC,T0001,7.11,0.21,2615,20384,2711,177,5,4,0,0,0,0,0
FILE,T0001,0,729,0,8601186,224748,0,0,0
NET,T0001,1.8,1.0,1.5,1.0
NETPACKET,T0001,7.3,6.1,6.4,6.1
NETSIZE,T0001,259.7,171.0,232.7,171.0
NETERROR,T0001,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
VGBUSY,T0001,6.2,0.2,0.2,0.0
VGREAD,T0001,3155.6,540.9,12.5,14.5
VGWRITE,T0001,220.4,107.3,28.3,0.1
VGSIZE,T0001,23.8,38.1,7.7,251.9
VGXFER,T0001,141.8,17.0,5.3,0.1
IOADAPT,T0001,0.0,0.0,0.0,3722.7,356.1,164.3
JFSFILE,T0001,18.8,20.5,94.6,52.2,79.0,0.2,84.5,0.1,83.4,70.8,55.7,0.0,0.0,47.5,14.9,55.2,91.0,95.9,95.8,80.5,21.1,21.1,12.2,6.2,0.6,3.9
JFSINODE,T0001,3.4,1.4,41.7,3.9,1.2,0.0,26.3,0.0,5.9,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.7,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
DISKBUSY,T0001,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.0,0.1,23.8,0.9,0.1,0.0
DISKREAD,T0001,0.1,0.0,0.3,488.6,12.5,12.4,0.0,39.6,2996.6,157.2,1.7,14.5
DISKWRITE,T0001,22.0,6.5,37.3,8.9,28.3,41.0,0.0,13.6,120.8,71.7,5.9,0.1
DISKXFER,T0001,3.6,1.6,0.5,9.6,5.3,3.9,0.0,1.3,122.7,14.8,0.7,0.1
DISKRXFER,T0001,0.0,0.0,0.0,7.8,1.1,1.1,0.0,0.4,108.5,10.6,0.2,0.0
DISKBSIZE,T0001,6.2,4.0,70.7,51.6,7.7,13.8,0.5,40.7,25.4,15.4,10.3,251.9
DISKRIO,T0001,0.0,0.0,0.0,7.8,1.1,1.1,0.0,0.4,108.5,10.6,0.2,0.0
DISKWIO,T0001,3.5,1.6,0.5,1.8,4.1,2.8,0.0,0.9,14.2,4.2,0.5,0.0
DISKAVGRIO,T0001,5.7,0.5,7.6,62.6,11.1,11.2,0.5,98.5,27.6,14.8,7.8,362.0
DISKAVGWIO,T0001,6.2,4.0,75.4,4.8,6.8,14.8,0.0,15.1,8.5,17.0,11.3,4.0
DISKSERV,T0001,0.4,0.4,0.9,1.0,0.4,1.9,0.4,0.9,2.3,0.7,2.0,1.6
DISKREADSERV,T0001,5.5,0.6,5.2,1.1,0.6,5.7,0.4,1.6,2.5,0.8,5.8,2.1
DISKWRITESERV,T0001,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.4,0.0,0.6,0.6,0.5,0.3,0.6
DISKWAIT,T0001,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
PROCAIO,T0001,144,0,0.0
TOP,19464642,T0001,2.08,1.48,0.60,7,48308,32624,23344,498928,0,0,BESClient,Unclassified
UARG,T0001,19464642, 1,BESClient, 7 , root, system,/opt/BESClient/bin/BESClient
TOP,5374162,T0001,0.22,0.00,0.22,17,632,8,632,29,0,0,syncd,Unclassified
UARG,T0001,5374162, 1,syncd , 17 , root, system,/usr/sbin/syncd 60
TOP,0262152,T0001,0.14,0.14,0.00,7,1024,0,1024,0,0,0,lrud,Unclassified
UARG,T0001,0262152, 0,lrud , 7 , root, system,lrud 
ZZZZ,T0002,00:30:39,15-NOV-2019
CPU01,T0002,12.1,6.9,3.2,77.7
CPU02,T0002,0.5,0.2,0.1,99.3
CPU03,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,99.9
CPU04,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU05,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU06,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU07,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU08,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU09,T0002,1.2,0.5,0.5,97.8
CPU10,T0002,0.0,2.8,0.0,97.2
CPU11,T0002,0.0,2.8,0.0,97.2
CPU12,T0002,0.0,2.8,0.0,97.2
CPU13,T0002,0.0,2.8,0.0,97.2
CPU14,T0002,0.0,2.8,0.0,97.2
CPU15,T0002,0.0,2.8,0.0,97.2
CPU16,T0002,0.0,2.8,0.0,97.2
CPU17,T0002,0.9,2.7,0.2,96.2
CPU18,T0002,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.0
CPU19,T0002,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU20,T0002,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU21,T0002,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU22,T0002,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU23,T0002,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU24,T0002,0.0,2.9,0.0,97.1
CPU25,T0002,0.1,2.9,0.0,96.9
CPU26,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU27,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU28,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU29,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU30,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU31,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU32,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU33,T0002,0.1,3.0,0.0,96.9
CPU34,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU35,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU36,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU37,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU38,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU39,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU40,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU41,T0002,0.0,0.1,0.0,99.9
CPU42,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU43,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU44,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU45,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU46,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU47,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU48,T0002,0.0,3.0,0.0,97.0
CPU_ALL,T0002,2.6,1.2,0.2,96.0,3.8,48
LPAR,T0002,0.246,6,48,16,2.00,128,0.00,1.54,1.54,1,0,2.57,1.23,0.02,8.46,0.86,0.41,0.01,2.82,1,0
POOLS,T0002,16,16.00,10.10,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,2.00
MEM,T0002,0.2,96.4,86.5,15797.4,36864.0,16384.0
MEMNEW,T0002,76.3,8.4,15.0,0.2,20.1,81.0
MEMUSE,T0002,8.4,3.0,90.0,960,1088,8.4,90.0, 9076000.0
PAGE,T0002,1827.7,1082.1,52.8,0.0,0.0,1022.9,2594.5,0.0
MEMPAGES4KB,T0002,1573824,7508,796790,0,796790,683207,960,1088,0,0,683207,0,883109,501068,0,3655,37024,0,122504,1069101,1144416,0,146441,1070707,1439840,0,974002,47532,0,0,1021796,57526,821513,119,2335390,9,920746
MEMPAGES64KB,T0002,491460,915,0,0,0,499187,60,68,0,0,490545,0,0,87225,0,0,7072,0,49146,404235,463164,0,79516,411015,205314,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,44312,12889,0,0,0
MEMPAGES16MB,T0002,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
MEMPAGES16GB,T0002,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LARGEPAGE,T0002,0,0,0,0,16.0
PAGING,T0002,15798
PROC,T0002,4.92,0.06,2313,18824,525,163,3,2,0,0,0,0,1
FILE,T0002,0,795,0,5883500,271729,0,0,0
NET,T0002,0.6,1.2,1.2,1.2
NETPACKET,T0002,6.1,6.8,5.7,6.8
NETSIZE,T0002,106.6,181.4,212.3,181.4
NETERROR,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
VGBUSY,T0002,0.8,1.3,0.1,0.0
VGREAD,T0002,531.3,3756.3,13.2,0.0
VGWRITE,T0002,83.9,215.3,14.0,0.1
VGSIZE,T0002,21.2,71.2,6.1,4.0
VGXFER,T0002,29.1,55.8,4.5,0.0
IOADAPT,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,4300.2,313.4,89.3
JFSFILE,T0002,18.9,20.5,94.6,52.2,79.0,0.2,84.5,0.1,83.4,70.8,55.7,0.0,0.0,47.5,14.9,55.2,91.0,95.9,95.8,80.5,21.1,21.1,12.2,6.2,0.6,3.9
JFSINODE,T0002,3.4,1.4,41.7,3.9,1.2,0.0,26.3,0.0,5.9,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.7,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
DISKBUSY,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.8,4.8,0.1,0.8,0.0,1.5,2.9,0.3,0.0,0.0
DISKREAD,T0002,0.0,0.0,747.3,2358.8,13.2,639.8,2.3,8.1,399.7,131.4,0.2,0.0
DISKWRITE,T0002,4.6,7.2,165.5,7.7,14.0,21.9,0.0,13.0,36.0,42.8,0.5,0.1
DISKXFER,T0002,1.1,1.8,10.8,31.4,4.5,9.1,0.0,2.8,16.1,11.8,0.1,0.0
DISKRXFER,T0002,0.0,0.0,9.4,29.6,1.5,7.1,0.0,1.9,12.1,8.6,0.0,0.0
DISKBSIZE,T0002,4.2,4.0,84.6,75.5,6.1,72.9,228.0,7.6,27.0,14.8,8.1,4.0
DISKRIO,T0002,0.0,0.0,9.4,29.6,1.5,7.1,0.0,1.9,12.1,8.6,0.0,0.0
DISKWIO,T0002,1.1,1.8,1.4,1.7,2.9,2.0,0.0,0.9,4.0,3.2,0.1,0.0
DISKAVGRIO,T0002,4.0,0.0,79.5,79.6,8.6,89.9,228.0,4.3,33.0,15.3,12.0,0.0
DISKAVGWIO,T0002,4.2,4.0,119.3,4.5,4.8,11.2,0.0,15.2,8.9,13.4,7.1,4.0
DISKSERV,T0002,0.3,0.3,1.9,3.2,0.4,1.9,18.7,5.6,2.4,0.4,0.8,0.3
DISKREADSERV,T0002,9.5,0.0,2.0,3.3,0.4,2.3,18.7,7.9,3.0,0.4,2.6,0.0
DISKWRITESERV,T0002,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.3,0.4,0.0,0.6,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.3
DISKWAIT,T0002,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
PROCAIO,T0002,144,0,0.2
TOP,19464642,T0002,2.06,1.50,0.56,7,48308,32624,23344,510941,0,0,BESClient,Unclassified
TOP,54722870,T0002,0.19,0.17,0.02,1,421976,270976,24988,165669,1,0,oracle,Unclassified
UARG,T0002,54722870, 1,oracle , 1 ,oracle11,oinstall,oracleFIN91DMO (LOCAL=NO)
TOP,0262152,T0002,0.17,0.17,0.00,7,1024,0,1024,0,0,0,lrud,Unclassified
TOP,5374162,T0002,0.15,0.00,0.15,17,632,8,632,29,0,0,syncd,Unclassified
TOP,18153496,T0002,0.15,0.13,0.02,1,421528,270976,24540,169140,1,0,oracle,Unclassified
UARG,T0002,18153496, 1,oracle , 1 ,oracle11,oinstall,oracleFIN91DEV (LOCAL=NO)
ZZZZ,T0003,00:45:39,15-NOV-2019
CPU01,T0003,23.8,6.7,15.3,54.3
CPU02,T0003,0.7,0.3,0.1,99.0
CPU03,T0003,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU04,T0003,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
CPU05,T0003,0.0,0.0,0.0,100.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a solution, just an ideia on how to group by IDs (T000x), then you can iterate over the groups and apply whatever you want based on the type (ZZZZ, CPU ...)

You will ended up with a map where key is the T000x and value is the list of lines that belong to a certain T000x

```
try {
        // Read all lines to a List
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));

        Map<String, List<String>> group = new HashMap<>();

        // Get only IDs -  T0001, T0002 ...
        List<String> t000s = lines.stream()
                .filter(line -> line.startsWith("ZZZZ"))
                .map(line -> line.split(",")[1]) 
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Filter lines by ID
        t000s.forEach(t -> {
            List<String> filtered = lines.stream()
                    .filter(line -> line.contains(t)) 
                    .filter(line -> line.startsWith("CPU") || line.startsWith("ZZZZ"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            group.put(t, filtered);
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, all you need are the lines that start with `"CPU_ALL"`. If you can add a new constructor to your CPUData class, it's relatively simple.

First add a constructor which accepts a string:

```
public CPUData (String line){
    String[] data = line.split(",");
    this.date = LocalDate.parse(data[0]);
    this.time = LocalTime.parse(data[1]);
    this.value1 = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
    this.value2 = Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
    ....
}
```

and then just stream the lines as you are already doing above and filter the lines which start with `"CPU_ALL"` and map them to a CPUData object

```
List<CPUData> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (Stream<CPUData> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))){
        list = stream.filter(line -> line.startsWith("CPU_ALL"))
                     .map(line -> new CPUData(line))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
//do whatever with the list of CPUData´s
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into the existing NMON parser which is already available. I provide below the link.

https://github.com/nmonvisualizer/nmonvisualizer/blob/master/src/com/ibm/nmon/parser/NMONParser.java

The above code is part of NMON visualizer. I provide the link here.

https://github.com/nmonvisualizer/nmonvisualizer